# Is it possible to clip/mask a div using html5 and canvas?

Tags: html, canvas, clipping, masking

I have a photo gallery that uses images "cut off" at an odd angle but the cut-out needs to be transparent in order to see the background. I had been able to get it to work using alpha masks but there must be a better way.

Rather than mask each image within the gallery, I wondered whether it might be possible instead to clip/mask the containing div using html5.

I've been able to find a jsfiddle, which I've changed slightly, but it clips an image - not a div. Now I'm having a complete brain freeze and can't think how to change it to clip/mask a div instead.

Some assistance would be much appreciated!

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/EyBPC/) using code below. Please advise if more info is required.

css:

```
body {background:#999}
#mycanvas {width:840px;height:457px;border:1px solid red;}
```

html:

```
<canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
```

js:

```
// Grab the Canvas and Drawing Context
var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Create an image element
var img = document.createElement('IMG');

// When the image is loaded, draw it
img.onload = function () {

    // Save the state, so we can undo the clipping
    ctx.save();


    // Create a shape, of some sort
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(840, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(840, 457);
    ctx.lineTo(162, 457);
    ctx.closePath();
    // Clip to the current path
    ctx.clip();


    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    // Undo the clipping
    ctx.restore();
}

// Specify the src to load the image
img.src = "http://www.donina.com/donina/clipper.jpg";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clip the div's by rotating using css3 other divs. At most you need four divs if you need random angles.

Comment: I can see how that might work if I had a plain background (as I do in the jsfiddle for demonstration purposes), however, the site background is patterned and the div needs to be properly clipped to see the background; not hidden by rotated divs.

Comment: Oh, then you're doing it wrong. You should include the div in those four divs and use overflow:hidden on them. Look at the (animated) example here: http://www.romancortes.com/ficheros/page-flip.html

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean (sort of), but I still can't see how it would make the overlapping area transparent so that the background is visible.  Please see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EyBPC/2/) with an example. The background needs to be visible through the blue bordered div.

Comment: Nevermind - worked out what I was doing wrong and it's all good. Many thanks TiansHUo for pointing me in the right direction!